# Identifying Xpath from html

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
<a tabindex="-1" id="TF0-2BTN" style="width: auto;" href="#TF0-2PANE" istablabel="1">Payroll</a>
```

I need xpath to identify this element by "Payroll" text input but not by @id and @href. Please help !!!

Comment: Please show more of your input HTML document. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this -

> //a[text()='Payroll']
>
> //*[text()="Payroll"]

and is your question answered ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like below?

`//a[@id='TF0-2BTN']`

**Update based on comment by the author of this question**

`//a[@id='TF0-2BTN' and . = 'Payroll']`

If you do not want to use the `id` attribute, then just use `//a[. = 'Payroll']`

Comment: yes it works but i need something like this //*a[text='Payroll']

Comment: @VimalRaj, have you check it?

Answer (score 0):

```
//a[contains(text(), "Payroll")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using contains text in xpath to find elements by using the text like below

```
  .//a[contains(text(),'Payroll')]
```

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
//a[contains(text(),'Payroll')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath which finds an element by exact text `//a[text()='Payroll']`